# How to run Visual Studio Code Analysis on Hudson-CI?

Tags: visual-studio, hudson, code-analysis

I have found how to integrate StyleCop and FxCop with Hudson, but what about Visual Studio Code Analysis? Can't it also be integrated into Hudson?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio Code Analysis is simply an extended version of FxCop.  If you want to include the addition rules shipped with VS Code Analysis, run FxCopCmd.exe from your VS installation instead of from a stand-alone FxCop installation.

Comment: Are you sure? AFAIK FxCop analyses only IL (compiled) code, while Code Analysis checks C# code.

Comment: I'm very sure.  Are you perhaps confusing VS Code Analysis with StyleCop?

Answer (score 1):

Unless someone has created a plugin for this specific purpose, you'll either have to write your own or you're out of luck. Having StyleCop and FxCop covers a lot though, so I wouldn't worry too much.